# Twig direct include doesn't work, only "with"ing specific keys does

Tags: twig, patternlab.io

I'm using Pattern Lab with twig templates and having an issue with using objects directly in the `with` statement in includes.

#### This is my `teaser-content-blocks` organism:

```
{% set content_blocks = [
  {
    teaser_photo: {
      url: 'https://img.buzzfeed.com/buzzfeed-static/static/enhanced/terminal01/2011/3/29/17/enhanced-buzz-14894-1301433714-5.jpg',
      alt: 'Man sleeping on a cake',
      title: 'Man sleeping on a cake',
      height: '200px',
      width: '400px',
    },
  }
] %}

<div class="teaser-content-blocks">
  {% for content_block in content_blocks %}
    {% include '@molecules/teaser-content-block.twig' with content_block only %}
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

#### This is the `teaser-photo` atom:

```
<div class="teaser-photo">
  <img
    src="{{ url }}"
    alt="{{ alt }}"
    title="{{ title }}"
  />
</div>
```

#### And this is what I'm *attempting* to do with the `teaser-content-block` molecule:

```
<div class="teaser-content-block">
  <div class="left">
    {% include '@atoms/teaser-photo.twig' with teaser_photo only %}
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    {% include '@atoms/title.twig' with { title: 'Sleep on a cake', element: 'h3' } only %}
    {% include '@atoms/teaser-body.twig' with { body: "When we say 'sweet dreams', this isn't quite what we mean! Check this mad lad not understanding the general concept of pillows! This utter banterboy has completely confused what he is meant to use as a confectionary-based celebration of one's birth and a soft item of bedding designed to cushion the head during sleep or light rest. Mental!" } only %}
  </div>
</div>
```

It seems, however, that the `with teaser_photo only` statement causes twig to break and not compile, with an error of `Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Twig_Template::display() must be of the type array, null given`.

If I change that include statement to the following:

```
{% include '@atoms/teaser-photo.twig' with { url: teaser_photo.url, alt: teaser_photo.alt, title: teaser_photo.title } only %}
```

... it works fine, but this is way too verbose for my liking. I'd rather just pass the object down as it is. It just seems to not want to pick it up in the correct manner, even though *theoretically* it should work the same.

I'm not a twig expert so I may be missing something really obvious.

Any help much appreciated as always!

Comment: Are you sure that's the problem? It does run on [twigfiddle](https://twigfiddle.com/sqcp2m)

Comment: +1 for twigfiddle, didn't know that existed! Super useful. How weird though, perhaps it's pattern lab's implementation of twig that's borked? Or could it be because pattern lab provides default values such as title? Thinking about it now...

Comment: Found the issue and answered my own question, cheers though mate

Comment: No problem Matt, the only thing the twigfiddle is missing are adding custom functions/filters :-)

Answer (score 0):

Discovered the issue. Pattern Lab of course tries to render every available pattern, so it was trying to render `teaser-content-block.twig` which is trying to reference the variable `teaser_photo`, which of course doesn't exist in this scope. So the cure was to replace that line with one that uses a default, like so:

```
{% include '@atoms/teaser-photo.twig' with teaser_photo|default({}) only %}
```

... or at least something that does a similar thing. Thanks to @DarkBee too for taking the time to have a look.